# referencing a method in an if statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I check if a method is or isn't running, in an if statement? For example-

```
if ([(UIButton *)sender isEqual:blueButton] && **showBlueText method is running** )
{
    Keep playing.
}
else if ([(UIButton *)sender isEqual:blueButton] && **showBlueText method is NOT running** )
{
    Game over.
}

-(void)showBlueText
{
blueText.hidden = NO;
[self performSelector:@selector(hideText) withObject:nil afterDelay:textDelay];
[self performSelector:@selector(showGreenText) withObject:nil afterDelay:hideDelay];
}
```

Just to clarify, 'showBlueText' is a part of its own loop that runs independently of this if statement. I'm just trying to check if showBlueText is currently running.

Comment: Define "running". Unless you are messing with threads, it's not going to be "running".

Comment: I have text that appears on screen for 1 second before dissappearing and calling the next text, etc. there are 4 of these text methods in the loop. I'm trying to check in the if statement if the "red" text method is happening when the "red" button was pressed.

Comment: So by "running", you mean "waiting for an animation to complete"? If that's the case, you need to post your animation code. What's in that `textLoop` method?

Comment: I appended the original question to include one of the methods I want to check on.

Comment: The method showBlueText will return immediately. There can not be more than one method "running" at the same time on one thread. You should simply check for the hidden property on blueText.

Comment: @phix123 I tried that and can't seem to figure out the syntax to only CHECK if it's not hidden and not actually try to change the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to record state here.  Make a new instance variable in this class.

```
// new iVar
BOOL textIsShowing;

// method
-(void)showBlueText {
  textIsShowing = YES;
  blueText.hidden = NO;
  [self performSelector:@selector(hideText) withObject:nil afterDelay:textDelay];
}

// method
- (void)hideText {
  textIsShowing = NO;
  blueText.hidden = YES;
}

// button press
- (void)buttonPressed {
  if (textIsShowing) {
    NSLog(@"Keep playing");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Game over");
  }
}
```

Between the time you call this method, and the animation stops, don't think of it as "running". It schedules code to be executed later. Instead you want to be notified after it has finally run.

And in this case it's easiest to keep track of the state yourself. Use a new variable to track the state of things, and change it's value when that state changes.

---

But can't you just check `if (blueText.hidden)`? Yeah, you could. But it's bad practice to store state about your program in some obscure property of a random unimportant object.

Examine your state to figure out what you show. Don't examine what's showing to figure out your state.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest replace `Keep playing` or `Game over` or `Doing stuff` with `NSLog()` statements. I always use it to keep a track of the changes in program if I am getting unexpected result.

So your statement may look like:

```
NSLog(@"Keep playing");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I actually have other code there, I just put that here to express what the code does in those portions without you having to read through a ton of irrelevant stuff. :)

Comment: so did I answer your question?

Comment: No, my question is about how I reference if a method is running in my if statement condition, not the body.

Comment: so do you want to check if the method is executed or not?

Comment: Yes I want to check if the method IS executing at the time of the button press, the idea is that you can only continue playing if while "Blue" is displayed you press the blue colored button. That's what I'm after with this if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the text is hidden.  No need to store parallel state in your controller - all that does is create the possibility that they'll be out of sync.